# SED Expression To Remove Everything After 3rd Dot

Tags: bash, sed

I have a version number that I need to truncate in *bash* so that I am left with **2.0.0**

Below is the string (version number):
**2.0.0.1603182415**

I have tried this sed expression, but I don't think it's quite right:

```
echo '2.0.0.1603182415' | sed 's/\..*//3'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try: `s='2.0.0.1603182415'; echo "${s%.*}"`

Comment: With `grep` you can use following: `echo '2.0.0.1603182415' | grep -o '^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*'` also.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo '2.0.0.1603182415' | sed 's/\.[^.]*//3'
2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[0-9.]*/\1/'
```

This will also work when there are more than two dots in the version:

```
echo '2.0.0.1603182415' | sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[0-9.]*/\1/'
2.0.0
echo '2.0.0.16031.82415' | sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[0-9.]*/\1/'
2.0.0
echo '2.0.0.16031.824.15' | sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[0-9.]*/\1/'
2.0.0
```